# Web-Push notification script working on Firefox but not on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, web-push

I am building a web push notification system and I am using the concept used in this example:

https://github.com/Minishlink/web-push-php-example

I have the following code in my JS file. It checks for API support, checks if notifications are not disabled, registers the service worker, asks for permission to display notifications, if allowed subscribes the user and sends the details to the server. If the user is already subscribed, it updates the endpoint value in the DB.

When I run this on Firefox 61, it works fine, but when I run it on Chrome 67 I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getKey' of null
    at pushSubscribe (notification.js:48)
    at navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then.then.subscription (notification.js:30)
```

My understanding is that Chrome does not detect the **subscription** when the service worker is registered and the user is subscribed, hence it gives the error. Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // Feature detection
    if (!('serviceWorker' in navigator)) {
        alert('Service Worker API isn’t supported.');
    } else if (!('PushManager' in window)) {
        alert('Push API isn’t supported.');
    } else if (!('Notification' in window)) {
        alert('Notifications API isn’t supported.');
    } else if (!('showNotification' in ServiceWorkerRegistration.prototype)) {
        alert('Notifications aren’t supported.');

    // Check permission
    } else if (Notification.permission == 'denied') {
        alert('Notifications are disabled.');
    } else {

        // Register service worker
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then(() => {
            navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(serviceWorkerRegistration => serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()).then(subscription => {
                if (!subscription) {
                    // Subscribe user
                    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(serviceWorkerRegistration => serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({
                        userVisibleOnly: true,
                        applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array('BNwjaNBKGM13IAef-gJr7C95W3yLJe2F5X0zLnwacN3zCnZK15Vqf3ijeHl9k7K0yBFX3ZwxAmldPoVDpi6iETA'),
                    })).then(subscription => {
                        return pushSubscribe(subscription);
                    });
                }
                // Update endpoint
                return pushSubscribe(subscription);
            });
        });

        function urlBase64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
            const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
            const base64 = (base64String + padding).replace(/\-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');

            const rawData = window.atob(base64);
            const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);

            for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
                outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            return outputArray;
        }

        function pushSubscribe(subscription) {
            const key = subscription.getKey('p256dh');
            const token = subscription.getKey('auth');
            const contentEncoding = (PushManager.supportedContentEncodings || ['aesgcm'])[0];

            return fetch('/scripts/notification-subscribe.php', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    endpoint: subscription.endpoint,
                    publicKey: key ? btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(key))) : null,
                    authToken: token ? btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(token))) : null,
                    contentEncoding,
                    user: userId, // generated beforehand
                }),
            }).then(() => subscription);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there any error on Chrome console

Comment: @SiddharthJain Yes, the error displayed in Chrome console is in the question.

Comment: Could you please debug at different level , i think subscription becomes undefined when it is called first time , could you just test if condition before subscription.getKey

Comment: @SiddharthJain Sorry, I couldn't clearly understand how to do the if condition check. The IF check under "// Register service worker" seems to be working fine on Chrome too.

Comment: In pushSubscribe function

Comment: @SiddharthJain I deleted everything in pushSubscribe() function and put this: "if (subscription) alert(subscription.getKey('p256dh'));" It returned "[object ArrayBuffer]" both in Firefox and Chrome, after clicking "Allow" on notification permission dialog.

Comment: could you please share fiddle 
or else just put all contents of push subscribe function inside if it will work

Comment: I added my test page to the question, if you open it in Chrome, you will notice the console error.

Comment: https://www.tutsandtips.com/scripts/notification-subscribe.php/ 404 () not found i am getting this error

Comment: I don't have the server script on this test page. This test page shows the error I am trying to solve. Did you see the console error I mentioned in my question, when you visited the test page in Chrome? The error is logged before clicking Allow button, before the info is sent to the server script, which is not sent in Chrome. Do not refresh the page after first visiting it. Just visit it after clearing the cache, so that you can see the console error. Also, can you please unlink that link to my site in your comment? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        if(subscription){
const key = subscription.getKey('p256dh');
            const token = subscription.getKey('auth');
            const contentEncoding = (PushManager.supportedContentEncodings || ['aesgcm'])[0];

            return fetch('/scripts/notification-subscribe.php', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    endpoint: subscription.endpoint,
                    publicKey: key ? btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(key))) : null,
                    authToken: token ? btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(token))) : null,
                    contentEncoding,
                    user: 1,
                }),
            }).then(() => subscription);
        }
}

Just modify this function hope pushSubscription with if block it works
```

Comment: Thank you, this removed the console error. But instead of doing the check in the function, I will do it before calling the function under // Register service worker.